# slider not working in multiple div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to call the slider script for four various `div` section (ie) my page has four slider. It is working for first slider only. Need to reuse the script for all slider `div` section. Now all slider are taken as single slider.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-red", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-red";
}
```

```css
.mySlides {display:none}
```

```html
<div class="w3-content" style="max-width:800px">

<div class="mySlides">
   <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
       <img  src="image/cunsulting-marchandise.jpg" style="width:100%">
   </div>
   <div style="width:50%;float:right;">
       <img  src="image/cunsulting-marchandise.jpg" style="width:100%">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="mySlides">
   <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
       <img  src="image/cunsulting-analytics.jpg" style="width:100%">
   </div>
   <div style="width:50%;float:right;">
      <img  src="image/cunsulting-analytics.jpg" style="width:100%">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="mySlides">
   <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
       <img  src="image/cunsulting-store-solutions.jpg" style="width:100%">
   </div>
   <div style="width:50%;float:right;">
      <img  src="image/cunsulting-store-solutions.jpg" style="width:100%">
   </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="w3-center">
  <div class="w3-section">
    <button class="w3-btn" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">Prev</button>
    <button class="w3-btn" onclick="plusDivs(1)">Next</button>
  </div>
  <button class="w3-btn demo" onclick="currentDiv(1)">1</button>
  <button class="w3-btn demo" onclick="currentDiv(2)">2</button>
  <button class="w3-btn demo" onclick="currentDiv(3)">3</button>
</div>

<div class="w3-content" style="max-width:800px">

<div class="mySlides">
   <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
       <img  src="image/cunsulting-marchandise.jpg" style="width:100%">
   </div>
   <div style="width:50%;float:right;">
       <img  src="image/cunsulting-marchandise.jpg" style="width:100%">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="mySlides">
   <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
       <img  src="image/cunsulting-analytics.jpg" style="width:100%">
   </div>
   <div style="width:50%;float:right;">
      <img  src="image/cunsulting-analytics.jpg" style="width:100%">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="mySlides">
   <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
       <img  src="image/cunsulting-store-solutions.jpg" style="width:100%">
   </div>
   <div style="width:50%;float:right;">
      <img  src="image/cunsulting-store-solutions.jpg" style="width:100%">
   </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="w3-center">
  <div class="w3-section">
    <button class="w3-btn" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">Prev</button>
    <button class="w3-btn" onclick="plusDivs(1)">Next</button>
  </div>
  <button class="w3-btn demo" onclick="currentDiv(1)">1</button>
  <button class="w3-btn demo" onclick="currentDiv(2)">2</button>
  <button class="w3-btn demo" onclick="currentDiv(3)">3</button>
</div>

<div class="w3-content" style="max-width:800px">

<div class="mySlides">
   <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
       <img  src="image/cunsulting-marchandise.jpg" style="width:100%">
   </div>
   <div style="width:50%;float:right;">
       <img  src="image/cunsulting-marchandise.jpg" style="width:100%">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="mySlides">
   <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
       <img  src="image/cunsulting-analytics.jpg" style="width:100%">
   </div>
   <div style="width:50%;float:right;">
      <img  src="image/cunsulting-analytics.jpg" style="width:100%">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="mySlides">
   <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
       <img  src="image/cunsulting-store-solutions.jpg" style="width:100%">
   </div>
   <div style="width:50%;float:right;">
      <img  src="image/cunsulting-store-solutions.jpg" style="width:100%">
   </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="w3-center">
  <div class="w3-section">
    <button class="w3-btn" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">Prev</button>
    <button class="w3-btn" onclick="plusDivs(1)">Next</button>
  </div>
  <button class="w3-btn demo" onclick="currentDiv(1)">1</button>
  <button class="w3-btn demo" onclick="currentDiv(2)">2</button>
  <button class="w3-btn demo" onclick="currentDiv(3)">3</button>
</div>
<div class="w3-center">
  <div class="w3-section">
    <button class="w3-btn" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">Prev</button>
    <button class="w3-btn" onclick="plusDivs(1)">Next</button>
  </div>
  <button class="w3-btn demo" onclick="currentDiv(1)">1</button>
  <button class="w3-btn demo" onclick="currentDiv(2)">2</button>
  <button class="w3-btn demo" onclick="currentDiv(3)">3</button>
</div>
<div class="w3-center">
  <div class="w3-section">
    <button class="w3-btn" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">Prev</button>
    <button class="w3-btn" onclick="plusDivs(1)">Next</button>
  </div>
  <button class="w3-btn demo" onclick="currentDiv(1)">1</button>
  <button class="w3-btn demo" onclick="currentDiv(2)">2</button>
  <button class="w3-btn demo" onclick="currentDiv(3)">3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried unique classes / ids for your slider?

Comment: Can you please try to post a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I know this will be ugly but Copy evrything to a new one for example: `Myslide1` is the first slider the second is `Myslide2`. Because u say that the img of Myslide should change.... yeah there are multiple Myslides.